# Literally impossible to install Ubuntu on Win8 laptop

Tags: dual-boot

I have tried countless times to boot from  a usb and also a disc... secure boot is off, but still in UEFI mode. Please guide me.. I love the look (I am using Virtual Box) and I want to be able to Dual Boot. Thanks

Comment: This instructions in [the UEFI article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) in the Ubuntu help wiki work for sure. I followed them several weeks ago and I succeeded. My laptop is SAMSUNG Series 3 NP350V5C-T01US with pre-installed Windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to wipe Windows 8 off completely? If so, I managed to do this myself. I cannot remember the exact steps (did it by accident) but I know I repaired Ubuntu from the Live CD. It ended up wiping my partition completely and fresh installed Ubuntu.

Hope that helps.

Edit: make a recovery CD of Windows 8 so you don't end up in my position and stuck with Linux only. Not a huge deal but it's seems almost irrevocable.

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have secure boot off:

- Use Windows 8 Disk Management to shrink your windows partition the desired amount to leave room for Linux (ONLY APPLYS IF SHARING SAME DISK)
- Boot from Installation media in UEFI mode(Not sure if applies to cds). My laptop lets me choose to boot devices with UEFI or normally. Choose UEFI. One of your F1-F12 buttons should give you a boot device selection menu. If you cant find this menu, going into BIOS should let you choose one manually or chnage the order of boot devices.
- During install choose "something else"
- Split the unused space into 2 partitions,a swap partition and filesystem of your choosing. Install the bootloader to the same drive your Windows is installed on.

Once done isntalling windows will no longer boot.

- Boot from installation media again but choose try Ubuntu this time.
- install boot repair
- Run boot repair using recomended settings and reboot.
- Enjoy